# I got this error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /tasks/ in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

```
   
 Environment:
    
    
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/
    
    Django Version: 3.2.5
    Python Version: 3.8.5
    Installed Applications:
    ['hello',
     'newyear',
     'tasks',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
    
    Template loader postmortem
    Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
    
    Using engine django:
        * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Enclave\Django_For_Web\templates\tasks\index.html (Source does not exist)
        * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Enclave\Django_For_Web\hello\templates\tasks\index.html (Source does not exist)
        * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Enclave\Django_For_Web\newyear\templates\tasks\index.html (Source does not exist)
        * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\tasks\index.html (Source does not exist)
        * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\tasks\index.html (Source does not exist)
    
    
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Enclave\Django_For_Web\tasks\views.py", line 7, in index
        return render(request, "tasks/index.html", {
      File "C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
        content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
      File "C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
        template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
      File "C:\Users\Enclave\AppData\Local\Programs\PythonCodingPack\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 19, in get_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
    
    Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /tasks/
    Exception Value: tasks/index.html
```

Comment: A template that is used in the code was not found. It was expected to be present at one of the locations given in the `Using engine django:` section.

Comment: Show your views.py and which related to the html page which you are trying to rendering